# Loading weights fails in keras

Tags: python, keras

Why does the following code fail if `a==b`, but work fine otherwise?
Error:
`ValueError: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 2 and 1 for 'Assign' (op: 'Assign') with input shapes: [12,12], [12].`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import keras

a = 12
b = 12
x = keras.layers.Input(shape=(a,))
y = keras.layers.Dense(b)(x)
model = keras.models.Model(inputs=[x], outputs=y)

model.save_weights("model.h5")
model.load_weights("model.h5")
```

I use python 3, TensorFlow 1.1.0 as backend and keras version 2.0.1.
OS is some Linux.

Comment: works for me on TensorFlow 1.3.0, Keras 2.0.8

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to Tensorflow 1.3.0 did not resolve the problem
However, *upgrading to Keras 2.0.8 did resolve the problem*.

Apparently, loading caused the issue rather than saving.